# How to specify firefox/chrome binary path in Jmeter webdriver sampler?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to set up webdriver sampler in Jmeter in my company's network. I have tried all the suggestions from the link
[1]: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered

But facing the error can not find chrome binary and browser has not been configured. Please ensure at least one webdiver is configured for thread group.

I have also specified the chromedriver path in chromedriver config.

Jmeter version: 5.1.1
Jmeter Plug-in: 1.3
Java version: 1.8

Can someone please help to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved after copying chrome/firefox binary to the default location:
C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local and also specifying the binary using
jmeter --Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe".

The root cause of the problem was the binaries are not installed in default location.

Answer (score 0):

C'mon, if you're going to automate Chrome browser - you need to have it installed, aren't you?

So given you install [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium) or one of its derivatives (including [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/)) - you will be able to run your test (hopefully)

If you already have Chrome installed - make sure that the `chrome.exe` or whatever is the appropriate binary for your operating system is in your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

---

For Firefox you need to provide [`webdriver.gecko.driver` property](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Usage.html) pointing to your [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) binary either via [*system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) or via [`-D` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=c:/somefolder/geckodriver.exe -t testplan.jmx
```

Comment: Yes. Chrome is installed on Windows10. But we don't have permission to view the path/environment variables. I have tried to take the chrome set up and put it in other folder and provide the path using OS Sampler. It opens chrome in set up thread group and web driver samper throws same error as above.

Comment: Tried the geckodriver solution by giving command line argument as well still same issue. Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Is there any other way we can specify the PATH during jmeter script execution.

Comment: I don't think you can modify system environment variables during execution, you should be able to do this **before** execution. On Windows `set PATH=c:\some_folder_where_firefox_is_installed;%PATH%`. On Unix and derivatives: `PATH=/some_folder_where_firefox_is_installed:$PATH && export PATH`. Then [launch JMeter from the same terminal](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like `jmeter -t test.jmx`